# How do customize django-registration (pass parameters, use other built-in forms)

Tags: django, django-registration

I a new to django and python. I have however managed to build a small part of my application and I am in the point where I want to add a user registration feature.

I have downloaded and installed django-administration and so far I have been impressed with the basic and default configuration. *BUT* upon trying to customize some of it's behaviour I am stuck for 3 hours now.

- How do I go about changing the *success_url*?
- How do I go about using *RegistrationFormTermsOfService()*?

The docs make it sound so **easy** but for a newbie like I am stuck and frustrated. It is too vague and assumes too much from newcomers.

Can anyone show me a very quick example on how to do this? What files to edit, etc.

Any reply would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for the last few hours.

Regards,
Wenbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From django-registration FAQ

How do I pass custom arguments to the views?
Part 3 of the official Django tutorial, when it introduces generic views, covers the necessary mechanism: simply provide a dictionary of keyword arguments in your URLconf.